# Loading a JSON file javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I wanted to get the json code on this [page](http://bcodek.com/new/stores.php) .

This is the the JSON code:

```
[{"idStore":"13","0":"13","Name":"1414141414144","1":"1414141414144","Phone":"123456","2":"123456","Email":"tretretr","3":"tretretr","Description":"aaaaaaaaaaaa","4":"aaaaaaaaaaaa","Ville":"zaeazezae","5":"zaeazezae","Address":"aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa","6":"aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa","MsPoint":"0","7":"0","idGenre":"14","8":"14","Image":"--","9":"--","Country":"zaeaze","10":"zaeaze","idUser":"21","11":"21","Lat":"0","12":"0","Lng":"0","13":"0"}]
```

I have no knowledge of ajax so i tried to parse the content of the output of the php file into `result.json`.

```
$fp = fopen('result.json', 'w');
fwrite($fp, json_encode($stores));
fclose($fp);
```

I used this ajax code to read my `result.json` file  since the script is not on the same page with the JSON output.

This is my `www` folder architecture:

```
www -> js -> app.js
    -> inedx.php
    -> Store.php
    -> result.josn
```

I am using `app.js` to load the data from the JSON file (created by the `Store.php`) and modify it. Then I use it in `index.php`.

```
var da = $.ajax({
    url: "../result.json",
    success: function (data) {
        var obj = JSON.parse(data);
    }
});

alert(da);
```

And the output was:

`[Object Object]`

Did i miss something?

Comment: I think you need to do `alert(obj);` in success function. As obj has the data.

Comment: also alerting an object is always going to give you `[Object Object]` due to how [Object.prototype.toString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) works. You should log it to the console with [console.log()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log)

Comment: i didn't understand you.

Answer (score 1):

In your code variable `da` is not the returned result but the ajax function itself.

The value of the JSON is stored in `obj` variable. but however its also an object and you can not just use alert for it. but however you can alert its properties like below:

```
var da = $.ajax({
    url: "../result.json",
    success: function (data) {
        var obj = JSON.parse(data);
         alert(obj.idStore);  //would show the idStore of the first element in Array
    }
});
```

If You want the `alert` out of the ajax function, you can do:

```
var obj;

    $.ajax({
        url: "../result.json",
        success: function (data) {
            obj = JSON.parse(data);
            runIt();
        }
    });

function runIt(){
 alert(obj.idStore);  
}
```

The other way to do it (**Not Recommanded**):

```
var obj, done = false;

    $.ajax({
        url: "../result.json",
        success: function (data) {
            obj = JSON.parse(data);
            done = true;
        }
    });

 var int = setInterval(function(){
if(done){ alert(obj.idStore); clearInterval(int);}
}, 100);
```

Comment: yep. my bad. I corrected it.

Comment: i want the alert out of the ajax function

Comment: it didn't work as well.

Comment: I changed my code please have look at it

Comment: by the way remove `[]` from the beginning of you JSON code

Comment: shoud i remove the "[" from the beginning and the "]" from the end? cause  i didn't find the "[]" in the begining.

Comment: rmove `[` from the begining and `]` from the end of :`[{"idStore":"13","0":"13","Name":"1414141414144","1":"1414141414144","Phone":"123456","2":"123456","Email":"tretretr","3":"tretretr","Description":"aaaaaaaaaaaa","4":"aaaaaaaaaaaa","Ville":"zaeazezae","5":"zaeazezae","Address":"aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa","6":"aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa","MsPoint":"0","7":"0","idGenre":"14","8":"14","Image":"--","9":"--","Country":"zaeaze","10":"zaeaze","idUser":"21","11":"21","Lat":"0","12":"0","Lng":"0","13":"0"}]`

Comment: the alert did not set-off.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117761/discussion-between-ashkan-mobayen-khiabani-and-abderrahman-msd).